# Issue with Time Conversion

Tags: java, time, data-conversion

I have write code to get time from long and get long from time. While I am running I can't get proper datetime from long. Can you help me to fix this issue.

> TimeConverterUtil.java

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;


    public class TimeConverterUtil
    {
        public static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        public static SimpleDateFormat usrFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm:ss:ms");

        public static String getDateTime(Long stamp)
        {
              Date date = new Date(stamp);
              return formatter.format(date);
        }
        public static Long getTimestamp(String date)
        {
            Date lFromDate1;
            try {
                lFromDate1 = usrFormatter.parse(date);
                return lFromDate1.getTime(); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Testing Program:

> TCTester.java

```
//$Id$

public class TCTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Long timeInLong = TimeConverterUtil.getTimestamp("28 Mar 13, 02:14:02:000");
        System.out.println(TimeConverterUtil.getDateTime(timeInLong));

        System.out.println("\n\n\n"+TimeConverterUtil.getTimestamp("28 Mar 13, 02:14:02:000"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? What is your expected output and what you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the milliseconds part of your input format string. You've got a format of:

```
"dd MMM yy, HH:mm:ss:ms"
```

but `ms` is being interpreted as "minutes then seconds", not "milliseconds". You want:

```
"dd MMM yy, HH:mm:ss:SSS"
```

Note that you're not including milliseconds in your *output* format string, so that part of the information will be lost anyway.

Also note that it's odd to use ":" between seconds and milliseconds. It would be more normal to use ".", so the input might be `"28 Mar 13, 02:14:02.000"`.